# Verify the value of an element in the json payload

Tags: javascript, json, api, jmeter, jsonpath

When we invoke the HTTP GET method, the API returns the data.
I want to evaluate that all the returned value of a particular input key value is as mentioned in the GET  URL.

URL that invoked:
HTTP Get method. -->

```
https://dummy.dns.com/Wells/resource?$filter=employee.address eq 'France FR'
```

The API returned the below response,

```
{"next":"https://dummy.dns.com/Wells/resource?$skip=10&$filter=employee.address eq 'France FR'","value":[{"customer.name":"Stefan Peter","customer.landlinePhoneNumber":"97642","employee.country.name":"France","employee.country.id":"FR","employee.address":"France FR","employee.latitude":49,"employee.longitude":7.6,"leave.count":0,"_id":"M1023453","_externalId":"WF3453","_name":"WellsFargo","_employeeType":["contractual"],"_employee":"WF3453","_customer":"M1023453","leave.sickCount":0,"leave.casualCount":0},{"customer.name":"Stefan Peter","customer.landlinePhoneNumber":"97642","employee.country.name":"France","employee.country.id":"FR","employee.address":"France FR Junk","employee.latitude":49,"employee.longitude":7.6,"leave.count":0,"_id":"M1023454","_externalId":"WF3454","_name":"WellsFargo","_employeeType":["contractual"],"_employee":"WF3454","_customer":"M1023454","leave.sickCount":0,"leave.casualCount":0},{"customer.name":"Stefan Peter","customer.landlinePhoneNumber":"97642","employee.country.name":"France","employee.country.id":"FR","employee.address":"France FR","employee.latitude":49,"employee.longitude":7.6,"leave.count":0,"_id":"M1023455","_externalId":"WF3455","_name":"WellsFargo","_employeeType":["contractual"],"_employee":"WF3455","_customer":"M1023455","leave.sickCount":0,"leave.casualCount":0}]}
```

Now I want to verify the key-value pair is same as the one I passed in the URL as an input /query parameter.

I am using JMeter as my client to evaluate the API functionality.
what is the custom assertion to evaluate.
The response is an array and it's size may grow until 100  or 200.
Can anyone please suggest. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) and set this:

- Assert JSON PATH exists: $..value[*].['employee.address']
- Check "Additionally assert value"
- Enter in expected value: France FR

[image: JSON Assertion]

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking to write the assertion using JSR223. can you please suggest me a solution?

Comment: Why do you want that when it's provided OOTB through this element ? Performance of JMeter will be much better using OOTB features.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which returns the aforementioned response
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).value.each { entry ->
       if (!entry.get('employee.address').equals('France FR')) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Expected "France FR", got "' + entry.get('employee.address') + '"')
       }
   }
   ```
3. That's it, in case of mismatch the sampler will be marked as failed:

   [image]

More information:

- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)
- [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)